# Ignoring carriage returns in regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently attempting to parse a conversation file in Javascript. Here is an example of such a conversation.

```
09/05/2016, 13:11 - Joe Bloggs: Hey Jane how're you doing?  what dates are you in London again? I realise that June isn't actually that far away so might book my trains down sooner than later!
09/05/2016, 13:47 - Jane Doe: Hey! I'm in london from the 12th-16th of june! Hope you can make it down :) sorry it's a bit annoying i couldn't make it there til a sunday!
09/05/2016, 14:03 - Joe Bloggs: Right I'll speak to my boss! I've just requested 5 weeks off in November/December to visit Aus so I'll see if I can negotiate some other days!

When does your uni term end in November? I'm thinking of visiting perth first then going to the east coast!
09/05/2016, 22:32 - Jane Doe: Oh that'll be awesome if you come to aus! Totally understand if it's too hard for you to request more days off in june. 

I finish uni early November! So should definitely be done by then if you came here
09/05/2016, 23:20 - Joe Bloggs: I could maybe get a couple of days  when do you fly into London on the Sunday?

Perfect! I need to speak to everyone else to make sure they're about. I can't wait to visit but it's so far away!
09/05/2016, 23:30 - Jane Doe: I fly in at like 7.30am so I'll have that whole day!

I'm sure the year will fly since it's may already haha
09/05/2016, 23:34 - Joe Bloggs: Aw nice one! Even if I can get just Monday off I can get an early train on Sunday
```

My current regular expression looks like this

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}),\s(\d(?:\d)?:\d{2})\s-\s([^:]*):\s(.*?)(?=\s*\d{2}\/|$)/gm
```

My approach is almost there and gives me 4 groups as expected

```
{
    "group": 1,
    "value": "09/05/2016"
  },
  {
    "group": 2,
    "value": "13:11"
  },
  {
    "group": 3,
    "value": "Joe Bloggs"
  },
  {
    "group": 4,
    "value": "Hey Jane how're you doing?  what dates are you in London again? I realise that June isn't actually that far away so might book my trains down sooner than later!"
  }
```

The problem arises when a message (group 4) contains a carriage return. (see the message at line 3 in the example snippet).

I've done some research and using

```
[\s\S]
```

does not solve my issue. The pattern simply stops and moves onto the next occurrence.

For the third conversation the message is cut off at the carriage return.

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sA3sB8/1)**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you need a way to match any char but a CR? Use `[^\r]`. Or any char but an LF? Then use `[^\n]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would like the pattern to not terminate once it reaches a CR

Comment: Do you mean CR as in `0x0D` or CR as in "the lines ends here" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}),\s(\d{1,2}:\d{2})\s-\s([^:]*):\s+(.*(?:\n+(?!\n|\d{2}\/).*)*)
```

(https://regex101.com/r/sA3sB8/2) which scans to the end of the line, then uses a repeated group to first check that the new line doesn't start with `\d\d/` (which is the start of a date on the next line(s)), and if it doesn't, to capture that entire line as well.

You can make the negative look-ahead a little more specific if you fear that two digits followed by a forward slash could hit any edge cases. It increases the number of steps, but would make it slightly safer.

If a user actually entered a newline followed by a date in that syntax, you might have problems as it would stop matching at that point. I doubt they would also include a comma and a 24-hour time, though, so that could be one way to handle that scenario.

**Example:**

```
09/05/2016, 23:36 - Jane Doe: Great! Let me give you my travel details:

10/01/2016 @ 6am - Arrive at the station
10/01/2016 @ 7am - Get run over by a drunk horse carriage (the driver and the horse were both sober; the carriage stayed up a bit late to drink)
10/01/2016 @ 7:15am - Pull myself out from under the carriage and kick at its wheels vehemently.

09/05/2016, 23:40 - Joe Bloggs: Haha, sounds great.
```

This is just an example (with the [corresponding fix](https://regex101.com/r/sA3sB8/3) of adding more specifics to the look-ahead to handle it) just to show how a user *might* add text that could break that particular revision of the regex.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't think of that. Thanks @OnlineCop!

Comment: Mind that regex101 does not support CRLF endings, there are only LFs. Do not rely on regex101 when testing inputs that should contain CR symbols.

Comment: Regarding the edge case, I agree that it'd be unusual for the user to enter the exact pattern I exclude

Comment: That is, until someone is specifically trying to break the feature. Then it might be amongst the first tries.

Comment: Updated it with something that SHOULD be able to better handle that kind of edge case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That is a good point. But it's not only regex101 that has problems with CR. You can always try `\r?\n` if you want it to work with either LF or CRLF.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @OnlineCop. I appreciate your help!